# Quality not changing in embedded vimeo video in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, vimeo, vimeo-player

We are embedding Vimeo videos in Android WebView and we are not using default vimeo player controls. According to guidelines,

https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/embed

We are setting a video quality(360p, 240p etc.) instead of auto (default one) before loading vimeo player and there is no change in quality(still auto). But if we use player controls, and change quality, it works as expected. We need quality to change if we set a custom one before loading player.

Answer (score 0):

As per Vimeo [documentation](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224983008-Set-a-default-quality-for-embedded-videos):

> The quality parameter is not currently supported on mobile devices or tablets. It will be ignored on devices other than desktop computers.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a way to trick the webview to thinking the device is a desktop one. https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/720